# For each filled cell in Excel worksheet keep the value before colon

Tags: excel, vba

For each filled cell (except cells in this format `./.:.:.:.:.:nan%`) that contains colon (":") I would like to keep everything before first colon (:). I tried but I am getting error

```
   Sub Split()
        Dim position As Integer
        Dim substring As String
        For Each i In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            position = InStr(Cells(i.Value, 1), ":")
            If (position > 0) Then
                substring = Replace(Left(Cells(i.Value, 1), position - 1), "[", "")
                Debug.Print substring
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: What error? What line? please. What is the cell content when you get the error? Please, basic steps of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

You don't declare what `i` is, but it looks like you want it to be a Range. (I would prefer a variable called say, `Cel`, but that's just me).

```
Dim i as Range
For each i in ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    debug.print LEFT(i,Worksheetfunction.SEARCH(":",i)-1)
Next i
```

Comment: It's not just you. `i As Range` is criminal.

Comment: It's not just you. `i As Range` is horrible.

Comment: It's not just you. `i As Range` is lamentable.

Answer (score 2):

If 'i' is a range, then you can't use it in Cells() as an integer. Use it like a range.

```
   Sub Split()
        Dim position
        Dim substring As String
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
            position = InStr(cel.Value, ":")
            If (position > 0) Then
                substring = Replace(Left(cel.Value, position - 1), "[", "")
                Debug.Print substring
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub
```

**Edit:** my eyes started bleeding every time I looked at `dim i as range`, so I changed it to `cel`. The variable name `i` is typically associated with the data type integer or long, so it's really grating to see it used for a range. It made you and others miss the actual issue of the original code, because we always assume that in `Cells(i` the variable is a number.